# PHP Instagram API Pagination

Tags: php, json, api, pagination, instagram-api

I am writing a program in PHP that retrieves the list of who a user is following on Instagram. The problem I have is that their API only returns 50 results per call, and the rest is paginated. 
I know that there is a 'next page' as the returned JSON has a pagination->next_url.
Currently, the code I have gets the JSON and decodes it. Immediately afterwards, a call is made to get the next page using the URL from the first API call.
Have a look:

```
    function getFollows($url){
        $client_id = "my client id";
        //echo "A url: ".$url."</br>";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($result);
        }
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/follows/?client_id='.$client_id.'&access_token='.$token;
    $first_page = getFollows($url);
    $second_page = getFollows($first_page->pagination->next_url);
```

What I would like to do instead is to check the JSON for a next url and make a call to the next_url. Then it would check the JSON from that url for a next url and repeat. All collected JSON would then be merged into one list which I can then iterate through to echo each individual person.
My question is how can I for every time there is pagination, get the next url, merge the JSON and repeat until there are no more pages to go through.

I could keep making $third_page, $fourth_page, but then that is pointless if the user has more than four pages of followers and if they only have 10 followers for example.

I have tried using an if function to check if there is pagination and array_merge(), but to no avail. Maybe I was doing it wrong. 
Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

-DH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a ready-made code, there is a point with pagination- https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Comment: Thank you. This will do nicely and seems easy to integrate with! Currently I am using a while loop to iterate through, I will probably edit it to use this.